# Unzip file using 7zip VBScript

Tags: vbscript

So I have this code to unzip a folder:

```
 ' Create folder to exctract from, and location of zip file
ExtractTo="\\se-st-file01\" & Right("0" & Year(Date),2) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) & "\"
Zipfile= "\\se-st-file01\" & Right("0" & Year(Date),2) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) & "\"& Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) & "file to unzip" & ".Zip" 

' Create object for zip file then extract items to set folder above
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesinZip=objShell.NameSpace(Zipfile).items
ObjShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip), &h100
```

It usually works but every now and then it bugs somehow and chooses to not extract all files which causes an error further down in my code. Therefore I would like to extract using the 7zip program instead.

How would I implement this in to my code?

Comment: Weirdly I get a sense of [déjà vu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu) with this question, you sure you've not asked something similar to this before?, even the code sample gives me shivers!

Comment: I have asked about a similar code but with Another issue. I know the name of the path is annoying but using Another path to describe would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   oShell.Run(ChrW(34) + "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" + ChrW(34) + " e  " + LocationOfZipFile + " -aoa -o" + LocationOfOutput)
```